# Merge 2 cypress script to 1

Tags: cypress

I have 2 different cypress script for running URL and take response
200. Need to combine both scripts to one and display response in each script. Can be possible? Here is my both scripts:

**Script1:**

```
describe('This is script1', function() {
    it ('status should be 200', () => { 
      cy.request({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'https://www.mywebsite1.com/website/getdoc', 
        followRedirect: false, 
        headers: { 
          'token': 'HKt7854UHTFGR78#78', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        }, 
        body: { "ordernr": "E123456", "doctype":"pdf" }, 
      }) 
      .then((response) => { 
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200) 
      }) 
    })
  })
```

**Script2:**

```
describe('This is script2', function() {
    it ('status should be 200', () => { 
      cy.request({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'https://www.mywebsite1.com/website/getdoc', 
        followRedirect: false, 
        headers: { 
          'token': 'HKt7854UHTFGR78#78', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        }, 
        body: { "ordernr": "E987654", "doctype":"xls" }, 
      }) 
      .then((response) => { 
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200) 
      }) 
    })
  })
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please try to restructure the 'expected behavior'?

Comment: I got the solution for this, thanks